Zephyr Rest API seems to lose data after a Test Cycle is deleted
I've recently been pulling our test executions from the Zephyr REST API to try and create some analytics based on our testing. While investigating a single Zephyr Test, I noted our engineers had deleted 5 test cycles between ~01/03/2024 and 07/03/2024. The API populates these executions with the "CycleName" being filled with "Cycle with Id X not found," which is great.
However, what has seemingly happened after this is that three valid test executions assigned to valid test cycles are not being pulled. In fact, all data between 09/03/2024 and 24/03/2024 is not pulling across any of our Zephyr Test tickets.
I'm wondering if anyone has encountered anything similar in the Zephyr Squads REST API or a possible fix to be able to rectify our missing data.
Best,
Stuck
